# How do you assign values faster in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

Hey I have created a small program in pygame to just create noise (white and black pixels) and repeatedly replace over itself with more noise:

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 1920
HIGHT = 1080

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Noise.py")

def update():
   for y in range(HIGHT):
      for x in range (WIDTH):
         pygame.event.get()
         num = random.randint(0,1)
         color = (0  ,0  ,0  ) if num == 1 else (255,255,255)
         screen.set_at((x, y), color)
      pygame.display.update()

def main ():
   running = True
   while running:

      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
      
      update()

main()
```

The program works tough it is too slow to create the effect that I wanted (run at 30 to 60 fps). The only way I can for now make if a bit faster is by dropping the resolution though I would prefer not to.

Is there a way to assign individual pixel color in pygame faster? or even mabe a better way of going about this?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm not so sure this question is really a duplicate of the other one. Yes, some of the answers of the other question could answer this question too, but this doesn't mean the question is actually the same. I think the other question is about *how* to draw individual pixels, whereas this one is more an *efficiency* concern.

Comment: @BlackBeans That's your opinion. In my opinion it is "duplicate". Don't treat others to undo their votes.

Answer (score 1):

What is actually expensive here is that you are calling `pygame.display.update()` very frequently, probably more than you can even notice. Instead, you should limit that call to, say, at most 60 times per seconds. To do so, just keep track of the last time you called it in your `update` function and, if it's more than `1/60s` ago, call `pygame.display.update()` and update the last time you called it.

Also, calling `set_at` directly on the screen object is somewhat wasteful, because it doesn't just set a value in a big array, it also triggers some flushing. So a better way to do that would be either to create a temporary `Surface` buffer in which you write the pixels, and then you blit it on the screen just before updating, or you can access it directly with a `PixelArray`, which provides a `list`-like API to a `Surface`, but then you have to manually "close" it (that is, flush it).

Comment: The problem still persists even if I update the screen after completing the image. There is still a gap of time in which the program takes time to create the next frame.